# Array for Checkboxes if condition is met

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am asking for some help regarding Checkboxes with tkinter. What I want to do is use an Array to store the values of the checkboxes. Afterwards, I would like to output the result of the list, which all the values possible.

Here is what I have right now:

```
def Submit():
        name = entry_name.get()
        residency = ''
        if rbtnValue.get() == 'intl':
            residency = 'intl'
        if rbtnValue.get() == 'dom':
            residency = 'dom'

        program = comboProgramming.get()
        
        courses = ''
        if programming.get() == 'COMP100':
            courses += '(COMP100)'
        if webDesign.get() == 'COMP213':
            courses += '\n(COMP213)'
        if softEng.get() == 'COMP120':
            courses += '\n(COMP120)'
        result = name + '\n' + program + '\n' + residency + '\n' + courses
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Information', message=result)
```

Added in to show setting of CheckButtons:

```
programming = StringVar()
cbtnProgramming = Checkbutton(text='Programming I', onvalue='COMP100', offvalue='', font = font, variable = programming)
cbtnProgramming['background'] = fColour
webDesign = StringVar()
cbtnWebDesign = Checkbutton(text='Web Page Design', onvalue='COMP213', offvalue='', font = font, variable = webDesign)
cbtnWebDesign['background'] = fColour
softEng = StringVar()
cbtnSoftEng = Checkbutton(text='Software Engineering', onvalue='COMP120', offvalue='', font = font, variable = softEng)
cbtnSoftEng['background'] = fColour
entry_name = Entry(tk, font=font)
n = StringVar()
```

I would like to do this for the `courses` value in the code. It already runs, but I would like to run it through a list. Thank you

Comment: The code you posted doesn't include any checkboxes. Can you please show us what you've tried?

Comment: I have added the code in

Comment: Please try to create a single [mcve]. It's not clear how these two blocks of code should be combined. It also doesn't look like you've attempted to save anything to an array.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.